# shown.bs.dropdown event never fires

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What am I missing here. I am trying to listen for the drop down event when the hamburger menu is clicked, and the menu is shown. I think it could be a markup problem, but can't see what I've done wrong.

```
<div id="head-nav">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top head-nav">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header head-nav__header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle head-nav__hamburger" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#bsm-navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand head-nav__logo" href="#">
             </a>
        </div>


        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bsm-navbar-collapse">
                <!-- mobile -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="/" class="head-nav__link">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/home-loans/" class="head-nav__link">Compare Home Loans</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/special-offer/" class="head-nav__link">Special Offer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/rate-chaser/" class="head-nav__link">Health Check</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about-us/" class="head-nav__link">About Us</a></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- desktop -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs">
                    <li><a href="/home-loans/" class="head-nav__link head-nav__link--first">Compare Home Loans</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/special-offer/" class="head-nav__link">Special Offer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="head-nav__link">Big Bank Fight</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/rate-chaser/" class="head-nav__link">Health Check</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/home-loan-calculator/" class="head-nav__link head-nav__link--last">Calculators</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>
```

```
/* Latest compiled and minified JavaScript included as External Resource */
$(function() {
     console.log('ready...');
      $('*').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
      // never called up, although I have bound to everything....
           console.log('called');
      });
 });
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhc0whr5/2/)

Comment: your dropdown is all the element on a page?

Comment: you want the call to happen when you click on the menu's links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this::

```
$(function() {
      $('#bsm-navbar-collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
      console.log('called');
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you. You saved me probably an hour trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a 'collapse' element with your button, not a dropdown.  try :

```
$('*').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
      // never called up, although I have bound to everything....
           console.log('called');
      });
```